# How to create secure conditional elements in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia

In old school server side languages like PHP or ASPX, HTML elements can be sent to the browser or not based on the user's authorization.  For example, in PHP we could:

```
<?php if (user->isInRole('Admin')) { ?>
   <select id="customerList">
      <option value="1">Customer 1</option>
      <option value="2">Customer 2</option>
   </select>
<?php } ?>
```

How is this done with Aurelia?  Do we still need to use a server-side language so that the element is never sent to the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty similar actually. You could use `if.bind=""`. Which basically removes it from the `DOM` if the condition isn't met. So for your example, you would have a user object that holds the current state of a user, and pass that into your function. So you'd have something like this:

```
<select if.bind="isAdmin(userObj.Role)" id="customerList">
     <option value="1">Customer 1</option>
     <option value="2">Customer 2</option>
</select>
```

So if that function returns `true`, then the select tag will be displayed. If it returns `false`, it will be removed from the `DOM`.

Comment: Having the object in the DOM and then removing it does not seem very secure.  Wouldn't the customer list show if javascript was turned off or under some error conditions?

Comment: If javascript was turned off, the entire app would be turned off considering it's purely javascript. So in essence there would be no routing or anything that would work. We haven't had any issues doing it this way. Now we also have admin only pages, so in the `bind()` method, we check to see if the user has the authority to visit the page. If it doesn't, we navigate them away.

Comment: @AlienTechnology I should mention that it is only rendered to the DOM if the condition passes. So it isn't rendered then removed. It's only rendered if that condition is ever met.

Comment: James is right. `if.bind` will not render the element unless the condition passes. This is in contract to `show.bind`, which only applies the css `display: none;` to it.

If you don't even want the bundled version of the element loaded into the client unless the user is authenticated, you'd need to split your authenticated and non-authenticated parts out into separate bundles and import / lazily load them only when the user is authenticated.